# Best way to pass model from partial view to controller using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase this question but I've been working on a table sorter as a way of getting to grips with AJAX and JQuery in ASP.NET MVC.

So far it works, using this code:

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<EH.SASS.TillStatus.Model.Models.TillTransactionsOnHold>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/mvctablesort.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="tablediv">
    <table id="empTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-attr="tillnetworkid">Till Network ID
                </th>
                <th data-attr="transactiontype">Transaction Type
                </th>
                <th data-attr="tid">TID
                </th>
                <th data-attr="transactionid">Transaction ID
                </th>
                <th data-attr="cardno">Card No.
                </th>
                <th data-attr="receiptno">Receipt No.
                </th>
                <th data-attr="scheme">Scheme
                </th>
                <th data-attr="amount">Amount
                </th>
                <th data-attr="date">Date
                </th>
                <th data-attr="resolved">Resolved
                </th>
                <th data-attr="dateresolved">Date Resolved
                </th>
                <th data-attr="resolvedby">Resolved by
                </th>
                <th data-attr="datecreated">Date Created
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Till.NetworkId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionType.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CardNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReceiptNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SchemeType.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resolved)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResolvedDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.EHLogin)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "TransactionsOnHold", new { id = item.TillTransactionsOnHoldUid_PK }, null)
                        @if (!item.Resolved)
     {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Resolve", "Resolve", "TransactionsOnHold", new { id = item.TillTransactionsOnHoldUid_PK }, null)
     }
                    </td>
                </tr>
   }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        sort("#empTable", "Home", "_heldTransactionTable")
    });
</script>
```

JQuery/AJAX:

```
function sort(tableid, controllername, actionname) {
    $(tableid).find( 'th' ).click(function () {
        var sortBy = $( this ).data("attr");

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "/"+controllername+"/"+actionname,
            data: "{ 'sortBy': '" + sortBy + "' }",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            async: "true",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tablediv").html('');
                $("#tablediv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }
        });     
    })
}
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult _heldTransactionTable(string sortBy)
{
        var tilltransactionsonhold =  db.TillTransactionsOnHold...

        if (sortBy == (string)Session["sortBy"])
        {
            switch (sortBy)
            {
                case "tillnetworkid":
                    tilltransactionsonhold = tilltransactionsonhold
                    .OrderBy(m => m.Till.NetworkId);
                    break;
                case "transactiontype":
                    tilltransactionsonhold = tilltransactionsonhold
                    .OrderBy(m => m.TransactionType.TransactionTypeUid_PK);
                    break;
                case "tid":
                    etc..etc..
            }
            Session["sortBy"] = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Session["sortBy"] = sortBy;
            switch (sortBy)
            {
                case "tillnetworkid":
                    tilltransactionsonhold = tilltransactionsonhold
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Till.NetworkId);
                    break;
                case "transactiontype":
                    tilltransactionsonhold = tilltransactionsonhold
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.TransactionType.TransactionTypeUid_PK);
                    break;
                case "tid":
                    etc...etc...
            }       
        }

        return PartialView(tilltransactionsonhold.ToList());
    }
```

You'll notice some of the code I removed to save reading time, and I also appreciate that it is not the best solution, it is a learning exercise, for which any bits of advice are welcome.

Filtering a brand new datamodel fresh from the database every time would suck in a widely used application, and it would be far more efficient to only filter the model itself.

My question is this: What would be a good way to pass the data model to the controller from the partial view without heavily modifying the existing code, so that I don't have to query the database as much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, posting back an HTML representation of your data is worse than useless. There's nothing reasonable you can do with that. The way one would typically handle this sort of thing is to have a hidden input for each row that records it's "order" and a hidden input containing some identifier to be able to determine which object to apply that order to. You'd have to update this "order" input any time the sort changed, but any good library should have some callback for that.

Then, you would post these field values, which in AJAX would either be as a JSON object or as `x-www-form-urlencoded` (the name-value pair jazz you often see in URLs, e.g. `foo=1&bar=2`). In your post action, you would use the id values to look up the corresponding objects and then apply the order values to those objects. Then, save the updates back to your database.